# What is proper way of starting a new nativescript-vue project with Typescript support?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, vue-cli, nativescript-vue, vue-devtools

I want to be able to use Typescript inside Vue instance methods, as documented in [blog page](https://nativescript-vue.org/blog/using-typescript-in-nativescript-vue/) of nativescript-vue.org

When I create a new nativescript-vue project with `vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template <project-name>` following warnings appear in the debug screen.

```sh
tns debug android
```

Always give the following error lines...

```sh
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> CreateElement(NativePage)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> CreateElement(NativeActionBar)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativepage), ElementNode(nativeactionbar))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> CreateElement(nativegridlayout)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> CreateElement(nativelabel)'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativegridlayout), ElementNode(nativelabel))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativepage), ElementNode(nativegridlayout))'
JS: '{NSVue (Vue: 2.6.10 | NSVue: 2.5.0)} -> AppendChild(ElementNode(nativeframe), ElementNode(nativepage))'
```

**What are these boilerplate warnings starting with JS:... lines?**

---

#### UPDATE

JS error lines started after I added `@vue/devtools nativescript-toasty nativescript-socketio nativescript-vue-devtools`

Even I remove them console warnings are stil there.

---

I was wondering, if [quick start](https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/quick-start/) page is outdated? 
Since [Vue-cli-template](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template) did not get any updates in last 30 days.

**NOTE**: Projects created with `tns create`  does not give such errors. Only vue-cli-template has warnings.

Comment: These are not warnings - these are the renderer logs. You can turn them off using `Vue.config.silent = true` in your main/app.js.

Comment: Would you please, write your answer in answer form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned lines in the log are not errors nor warnings - they are renderer logs.

These can be turned off via

```js
Vue.config.silent = true

// Since NativeScript-Vue 2.5.0-alpha.3 the renderer logs
// can be disabled keeping other useful logs intact via
Vue.config.suppressRenderLogs = false
```

in `app.js` or `main.js` (depending on the template used).